# What Voltage Regulators Do I Get?

Tags: amplifier, voltage-regulator

Here is an amp that is going into protection mode:[image: Amp with burnt voltage regulators]

The two (correct me if i'm wrong) voltage regulators circled in red appear to be burnt.

Up close image of the voltage regulators:
[image: Bad burnt voltage regulators]

I believe that simply replacing these components may have a chance in fixing the amp. Unfortunately, I am not sure which voltage regulators I need to buy, when I look up "KIA 7815A PI 437" and "KIA 7915PI 449" I find similar components but with a different 3-digit ending. Are these digits important, or should I make sure that I am looking for  "KIA 7815A PI XXX" and "KIA 7915PI XXX"?

Comment: I am not convinced they are burned out. They look a little cooked, but that is not unusual, those regulators run hot. They usually look a lot worse than that when they go. Plus if the amp is going into "protection mode" it must be getting some power from somewhere. Check them with a multi-meter.

Comment: That also looks like some nasty cold soldering...

Comment: Good idea, i'll put my multi meter to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7815/7915 are standard parts. They're +15 and -15V regulators.

Every manufacturer has their own version with different letters... Like KA7815, LM7815, etc...

These things are total bog standard and compatible, so pick the one from the closest shop and solder it in.

Then, maybe there was a reason why they burned... and maybe the new ones will burn too... but they're so cheap, you can do the test.

Comment: @Guest Man: and the "PI" is probably a package code (which varies between makers), and the final three digits probably a date code.